# what is the difference between spring Maven Web Project and spring web project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to spring framework and Maven. I search it but its very diverse and I could get a concert answer. What is Maven? Is it like git?

Comment: Did you type `what is maven` into google?

Comment: A while ago I also didn't know what it was but once you Google it enough and read on Maven's main page you should understand what it is about. Come back with a more specific question if you get one while reading about it.

Answer (score 6):

Maven is a build system for java projects (like ant, gradle, buildr, etc.) Therefore, a 'maven web project' would be a web project that uses maven as a build system, whereas a 'spring web project' is just a spring based web project, and it doesn't say anything about which build system is used.